# options for condition variable in windows server 2003

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Windows Server 2003/ Win Xp does not support condition variables, what could be other options for functionality of condition variables in win server 2003?

Comment: Either you opt for not supporting Windows XP or you must cope with what the OS offers, if former is not an option.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I am looking for alternatives to condition variables...are there any?

Comment: You can build condition variables out of the primitives that already exist.  See boost's implementation of boost::thread::condition_variable.  [Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html), [Source](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/thread/win32/condition_variable.hpp)

Comment: @gimpf Not just "see", use.

Comment: You are more than correct about that.

Comment: Or switch to Visual Studio 2012, which supports std::thread.  (And I believe vs2012 now runs on XP.)

Answer (score 0):

Critical sections, mutexes, semaphores, events.  Windows has all the usual synchro primitives.

Comment: No, why? It's an usable answer. An event is a condition variable, if you want to look at it that way -- only with less sugar.

Comment: All the usual synchro primitives?  The important primitives are mutexes and conditional variables; the others can be synthesized from them (but might be more effective if implemented directly in kernel).  After those, the most useful one is a rwlock.

Comment: -1: A Windows Event is most assuredly _not_ a condition variable.  The OP asks specifically about condition variables.  See http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/win32-cv-1.html for just how hard it is to implement condition variable-like functionality using Event.  The value of condition variables is that they atomically release a mutex and start waiting.  Trying to simulate this with events without running into subtle missed signal races is really hard.

Comment: ..which is why I thought about changing to a comment.  The 'important primitives are mutexes and conditional variables' is, at least, arguable.  Semaphores and mutexes have been available on every multitasking OS I have used since... forever.  That's more than can be said for condition variables - a monitor-like construct that, on some OS, tends to not actually work correctly. Windows semaphores, critical sections and mutexes do not suffer from spurious wakeups, (AKA 'spurious failures').

Comment: Spurious wakeup is a red herring.  It is [solved in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait), and is irrelevant since you need the while loop (implicitly or explicitly) to test your invariants any way.  But this ship has sailed.  The C++11 committee and the pthreads committee both chose condition variables over semaphores or events.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773/pthread-cond-wait-versus-semaphore is a good example of why.  Cvars atomically release/acquire the mutex simultaneously with starting/finishing the wait.  Semaphores and events don't.