# New to using p_thread & semaphores, how would you use a semaphore to wait for a child thread to finish? (without p_thread join)

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

New to using p_thread & semaphores, how would you use a semaphore to wait for a child thread to finish? (without p_thread join)

Comment: imho that is not possible in a fully reliant way. It is not guaranteed when your thread main will execute, so any locking method is not reliant (spawned thread locking, main thread waiting for unlock).

Answer (score 0):

This can not be made to work with just one semaphore as @MarioTheSpoon commented. You'd need another semaphore for interlocking:

Main:

- `sem_init(1)`
- `sem_init(2)`
- `sem_trywait(1)`
- `sem_trywait(2)`
- Spawn child
- `sem_post(2)`
- `sem_wait(1)`

Child:

- `sem_wait(2)`
- `sem_post(1)`

Comment: Also, this answer is good for explaining where a condition variable plus a mutex are a better option than semaphores: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773/pthread-cond-wait-versus-semaphore

Comment: I'm not following why you claim that two semaphores are required for the OP's stated purpose, @meaning, nor what you claim is gained with respect to that purpose by the specific pattern of semaphore operations you lay out.

Answer (score 0):

> New to using p_thread & semaphores, how would you use a semaphore to
>   wait for a child thread to finish? (without p_thread join)

You can't, at least not with the POSIX semaphore implementation.  POSIX semaphores have no particular behavior when a thread terminates, so they cannot provide a signal of thread termination *per se*.

But one thread can wait on a semaphore that initially has value zero and is incremented only by another thread, explicitly, *before* that other thread terminates.  That's not the same thing as waiting for the thread to terminate, but it may be close enough for your purposes.