# Posix semaphore equivelent of Pthread mutex lock for mutual exclusion in C

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, semaphore, mutual-exclusion

Using this section of code below as an example (courtesy of https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/condition-wait-signal-multi-threading/) what would be the method of converting a `pthread_mutex_lock()`  and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` to POSIX and achieve mutual exclusion between functions.

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
pthread_cond_t cond1 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; 
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int done = 1; 
void* foo() 
{ 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 
    if (done == 1) { 
        done = 2; 
        printf("Waiting on condition variable cond1\n"); 
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &lock); 
    } 
    else { 
        printf("Signaling condition variable cond1\n"); 
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond1); 
    } 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); 
    printf("Returning thread\n"); 
    return NULL; 
}
```

Comment: _what would be the method of converting a pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_mutex_unlock() to POSIX ..._? I'm not sure what you mean by "converting to POSIX" because `pthread_*` _is_ POSIX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pthread\_cond\_wait versus semaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773/pthread-cond-wait-versus-semaphore)